overcoming background negative feelings: giving up, tired, defeated, depressed, hopelessness
Please provide sources from the original text or your own experiences and understandings of how to make progress in overcoming background negative feelings? For years I have been greatly harmed by harboring these feelings in the back of my mind which has not only created great suffering but altered the course of my life. Doing some mindfulness work made me realize that these feelings are there in my mind due to past experiences, and are harming me more than anything else in my life.
How can I overcome, even slightly, this kind of mindset?

Seems like there is a low level of energy both mental and physical. Do you do regular physical exercises?

@Desmon I actually meant mental tiredness rather than physical, but yes you are right it may have something to do with physical exercise - i barely get any other than walking during commute

I cycle: for hours and/or every day, easier for me now than walking, outdoors, go places, cheaper than the bus everywhere is nearer; the body had to get used to it, e.g. for several weeks or months, but that was many years and tens of thousands of kilometres ago. I bought a bike that was better than cheap but less than a year of using the bus, and it doesn't need much maintenance (i.e. replacement parts), 2 to 4 times per year maybe.

One of my Buddhist mentors once told me: if you feel you're depressed, defeated, powerless and cannot change anything, say to yourself: "now I will clap my hands" and then clap your hands.
See? You just decided something and accomplished it! Then say to yourself: "I will go wash my face", and do it. Then say: "I will clean my room", and do it.
Then say: I will sit down and breath. I will not think this negative thought. I will think this thought instead.
Do not try to fix too much too fast. Start with right where you are. Achieve a good peaceful moment with a tiny scope, with nothing in it. Stay in it for as long as you need to get comfortable. And then little by little you can expand. Paint your door. Plant some flowers.
As you expand, remember you cannot change the entire world all at once. But you can make helpful acts that will make it better one inch at a time.
Once you have found your peace and control in the present moment with nothing in it - just you and your two hands - you can carry it with you everywhere, like a snail carries its home. If your mind gets frustrated, you can draw it back to that zero-dependencies place.
You know what that place is called? It's called Nirvana. I'm not kidding . You can find it by clapping your hands.

Beautiful answer! Thanks

A Volkov has given a nice answer. I will give you an answer to transform your mindset. You said your past experiences are creating bad feelings in your mind.
You need to understand Anatta. Buddha said Sabbe Dhamma Anatta. It means all conditioned and unconditioned phenomena are not self. If you understand this fully you will not think that I did this , I did that etc … you will just disown your past… You will disown your body , feelings , perceptions, choices and consciousness. You will disown it because Sabbe Sankhara Anicca, meaning all conditioned phenomena are impermanent therefore all conditioned phenomena are source of suffering. It is not easy to disown. Buddha renunciated his wealth , kingdom and family. The situation is so bad.
Dedicate your life to understanding Buddha. Believe in Buddha. Die for Buddha.
That’s all I will say at the moment. Suffering is nothing new. Everyone is going suffer in much more worse ways than you do.You have time. Try to escape from it.
For immediate solution focus on Mudita. Meditate on mudita.
Mudita means sympathetic joy. Be joyful for whatever you have or you can accomplish. Be joyful for what others have and what others can accomplish. Be joyful for what your enemies have and what your enemies can accomplish. Be joyful for what every living being has and what they can accomplish. Smile. Laugh for the above reasons. Dance for the above reason.
Do this for a year and return to deeper meditation topics after you have learned to have sympathetic joy.

i upvoted this but 'sympathetic joy' might not be the best translation of mūdita at all times, vicarious or empathetic works well too..

@blue_ego one should celebrate one’s own achievements as well. That’s why vicarious happiness may not be the right translation.

i think it might even mean lenity - don't be so hard on yourself

Personally, I feel that a difficulty when stuck in mild to moderate depression is recognizing that we have reached a nadir in our life. Failure to do so could mean sliding into severe depression instead of turning it around. (Note: I cannot stress enough that if there are any suicidal tendencies, this could be a sign of severe or major depression and prompt medical intervention is needed).
However, I think the fact that one is able to recognize the mental and emotional rut early is a good sign. Unfortunately, once our mind is stuck in a rut it is hard to break free as trying to muster any motivation seems impossible. This is because of the low physical and mental energy within us. One of the most effective and sustainable solution is physical activity or workout. Personally, I find that stress is not necessarily bad if it can be turned off. Given time to recuperate and recover, our body and mind will naturally emerge stronger from past stressful events.
However, the problem with certain stress that we faced in life is that we cannot turn them off at will. The relentless onslaught just keeps coming; 24x7, day in and day out. The problem with such uncontrolled stress (e.g. from past emotional difficulties) is that there is no opportunity for our body and mind to recuperate and emerge stronger. And without a chance to grow stronger against both mental and emotional stress, our mind instead weakens thus we find ourselves stuck in a tailspin. I find workouts to be an effective way out of this vicious cycle; we can think of them as a kind of controlled stress that we can turn off at will.
One form of physical workout that I can recommend is brisk walking in a park (or any quiet place with lots of greenery). Try to maintain a duration of more than 30 minutes or gradually work towards this target. By willing your body to go at a rapid walking pace, we are stressing our mind in addition to stressing our body. The advantage of controlled stress is as follow:

We are channelling the type of stress that our mind engages in thus robbing it of opportunity or energy to engage in uncontrolled stressful activities (e.g. reminiscing past difficulties).
As it is controlled stress, we can turn it off. Giving our mind and body time to recuperate and grow stronger.
Surprisingly, by training our mind against controlled stress, we are also strengthening it against uncontrolled stress.

After working out a sweat, I find there is usually a perk in my mood. This is explained by science as due to the release of dopamine after physical activity.

Notably, dopamine release enhancement was still seen after a week of rest, showing that the effect of exercise extends beyond the exercise period

Although the above relates to exercises in mice, personally, I find even when I do less strenuous workouts, my improved mood can persist for the whole day. Once the mood had improved, we can then try meditation albeit now with a stronger mental and emotional foundation. May this be helpful, with Metta.
Addendum
One of the misconceptions is that monks during the time of the Buddha does nothing but meditation all day long. Even the Buddha was recorded to hardly stay in one place in the sutras but moved (of course by foot) from places-to-places teaching throughout his entire life. He was only known to stay longer in certain places towards the end of his life when his physique weakened. And when staying in one place, the Buddha and his monks were known to travel distances, walking, to visit householders for alms as mentioned here in Dhp 225 and in many other sutras. From such accounts, we know that daily walking as a form of physical activity is quite normal then. It is the sedentary lifestyle of this modern era that is somewhat abnormal instead.
